# If I generate a hash for a file stored on a network share, is the entire file sent over the wire? If not why?

Tags: file-sharing, hashing

Scenario: I would like to generate a hash of a file stored on a remote server. For this example lets say we are using windows file sharing for both the client and the server. I, as the client, locate the file on the remote file share. I then use some utility of some sort to generate a hash of the file in question. Also, just to be clear, we are looking for a hash of the file not its path. So, to complete the task, does a complete copy of the file have to travel over the wire in order for us to complete the hashing task?

Comment: Not sure if this one should be on serverfault or not.

Comment: Are you asking the hash is calculated at the client in the first place, or that the encrypted file is sent over the wire before you can apply the hash to decrypt it?  Where is the plaintext file located?

Comment: If you can manage to run a command/script on the server to calculate hashes and send back to you, obviously the files won't travel over network.

Comment: No encryption is assumed. Lets say for the sake of this example its a .ISO sitting on a windows share. We are the client and do not have any administrative access to the server. We are simply trying to get a hash of the file to use as a unique identifier.

Comment: How would you expect a local process to calculate the hash without reading the file?

Comment: The question was to settle a dispute. My assumption was that the file needed to be copied locally to compute the hash. The other person i was talking to said that they were able to get a hash of a remotely stored ISO in 10 seconds. I argued that he was missing some detail because he couldn't explain how the hash was computed so fast. To the other person it just meant that any remote file could be hashed that quickly. To me it only says, if true, then some detail in how the system worked was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the whole file is pulled down because the calculation of the hash occurs on the local system.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran an experiment using the Powershell `Get-FileHash` cmdlet and my results suggest that davidgo is correct.  First I hashed a 4.5 GB ISO image that was hosted on a remote server (specifically, a CIFS share on a Netapp filer).  I got a result in 2 minutes and 17 seconds.  Then I copied the file to my local disk.  That copy operation by itself took 1 minutes and 43 seconds.  I then ran the hash operation again, and I got a result in 1 minute and 7 seconds.  Those numbers don't quite add up, but I don't know why.  At any rate, hashing a local file was quicker by 50%.

Comment: The difference herr can likely be largely explained by the time to write the file to disk in the second case, and to a much lesser extent other traffic on thr network.